# How to convert string without ":" to const uchar *addr?

Tags: c++, dns

I must convert string like this "FE80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0012" to const uchar *addr without ":".

I tried split string without ":" and put like vector,...

```
vector<string> addressIPv6(string serverIP)
{
    istringstream iss(serverIP);
    std::vector<string> tokens;
    std::string token;

    while (std::getline(iss, token, ':')) {
        if (!token.empty())
            tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Would be acceptable to remove the ':' from the string and then use c_str() to extract the char*? https://onlinegdb.com/BkYpu_mXS

Comment: The only reason to convert an IPv6 string to a `uchar` array is if you need the *binary* representation of the IP address. Removing the colons is only half the process. You also have to parse the hex pairs into numeric bytes, too.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a set character from a string you can use the STL algorithms erase and remove

```
std::erase(std::remove(serverIP.begin(), serverIP.end(), ':'), serverIP.end());
```

Then you can use serverIP.c_str() to get the const char* and cast a copy of it if necessary to unsigned char*
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str